# Django Models: Reference the same field twice in a fk model

Tags: django, model-view-controller, database-design, django-models

So here's the issue i'm having with this Django Model.

I have a foriegn key to class SecretSantaGroup in class assignees called group.
I want to reference this fk in creator and assignee.

pretty much the data I want is like this:
creator = self.group.members
assignee = self.group.members

But I'm having issues on going about it and could use some help.

I want to be able to reference all the users in that specific group, just having trouble going about it.

```
class SecretSantaGroups(models.Model):
    groupName = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.groupName

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Secret Santa Groups'

class assignees(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(SecretSantaGroups)
    #person that gives gifts
    creator = models.ForeignKey(self.group.members, null=True)
    #person who receives gift
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(self.group.members, null=True)
```

EDIT
---I used terrible wording, the assignees class is supposed to be who gets who in the group. 1 person gets another in each secret santa group. so gifter and giftee

```
class assignees(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(SecretSantaGroups)
    #person that gives gifts
    giver = models.???(self.group.members, null=True)
    #person who receives gift
    giftee = models.???(self.group.members, null=True)
```

Comment: Your "assignees" model makes no sense. What are you expecting the foreign key for creator and assignee to resolve to? Also, I would suggest using proper naming conventions for your models; singluar form and TitleCased. Python class names should *always* start with a capital letter.

Comment: I wasn't too focused on the naming convention. I want creator and assignee accessing the members in group. I'll fix the convention after they are linked up.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense. Do you want to reference a specific user but only from the users that are in `group.members`?

Comment: I want to reference a single user in a secret santa group.

Comment: Total user: w x y z. Santa group foo has users x y,  I want to be able to access only the users in foo, not all users

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to do with the `assignees` model. You need to define creator as a ForeignKey to User on that model for one, but what does "assignee" represent? Seems like you just need to add an additional M2M on `SecretSantaGroups` and move `creator` there as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input Brandon. I did use some terrible wording, which I will fix. creator is the person who gets the gift for the assignee.  Creator gives gift to assignee. terrible terrible wording on my part

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, it seems like what you're trying to do is define an association with all *possible* users for the `SecretSantaGroup` and then define which of those users is "assigned" or whatever you want to call it.

I also don't know if you want to edit these within Django admin, or part of a different view, but how I would define the model is as such:

```
class SecretSantaGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')
    members = models.ManyToMany(User, related_name='members')
    assigned = models.ManyToMany(User, related_name='assigned', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

If you want to limit the choices of "assigned" in Django admin, you'll need to do this in two steps. First, you would need to assign which members, then you'd need to assign the QuerySet of "assigned" to the objects in `members` so the choices are limited, and then you can assign which ones you want.

This can be done via a custom form. I have NOT tested this code:

```
class SecretSantaGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SecretSantaGroup

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecretSantaGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['assigned'].queryset = self.instance.members.all()
```

Then you can assign the custom admin form on your model admin.

If you're doing this on the public side, you'll still need the same type of override, and you'll still have to do this in two steps, as best as I can tell. Hope that helps you out.